# Print multiple ruby variables on the same line

Tags: ruby, environment-variables

Is there any method to print multiple ruby variables on the same line?
Like in the example below:

```
env = gets()
name = gets()
puts "Deleting #{name} in #{env}"
```

I'm trying to put this variables in a system (cmd) also, and I can't set these two variables in the same line... the output is :

```
Deleting name
in env
```

Thanks,
Vlad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
env = gets().chomp
name = gets().chomp
```

Comment: Great, it's working with chomp...thanks a lot for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working exactly as it should. Just remove the newlines from the two strings before printing them.